# $\langle x,y \rangle, \ x,y \in \mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ reducible $\iff$ $\text{tr}[x,y] = 2$

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

I don't understand this statement that I am trying to prove that can be found in [this](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-6720-9) book (p.52):

> $\langle x,y \rangle, \ x,y \in \mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ reducible $\iff$ $\text{tr}[x,y] = 2$

In my version of the book, the statement looks as follows:

[image]

Either way, $[x,y] = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy $ is defined as the commutator of $x$ and $y$ and *reducible* is defined through all elements of $\langle x,y \rangle$ sharing a fixed point in their action on $\hat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty \}$, given by:
$$ \gamma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C}), \qquad \gamma\cdot z = \frac{az+c}{cz+d}$$

So far, I have been unable to prove either direction. My current approach, uses $\mathrm{tr}([x,y])= 2 \iff [x,y]$ is parabolic, meaning it has only a single fixed point. First, I am considering the transformations that fix $0, \infty$, which allows me to think in a simpler geometric way about $x,y, [x,y]$, but I have been unable to get the desired result.

Comment: They mean the group commutator, not the Lie algebra one.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: @Pedro, thank you for pointing that out! I corrected the post so that it fits my current issues.

Comment: Assume the matrices x and y are given as upper triangular. What are the diagonal entries of their inverses? What are the diagonal entries of the commutator?

Comment: @ahulpke You indeed get a matrix of trace $2$ for the commutator. It represents a translation. The conjugacy matrices are determined by the Fixed points and the number of them. This does sound promising.

Comment: At the very least, you should fix the typo (not "fix" but "fixed"), introduce a notation (say, $X$) for a matrix corresponding to the given element $x\in PSL(2,C)$ and verify that the condition $tr([x,y])=2$ (for $x, y\in PSL(2,C)$) is well-defined, since it really means $tr([X,Y])=2$. Then verify that "reducible" is equivalent to the property that $X, Y$ can be simultaneously conjugate to upper triangular matrices.